# OCSP Must-Staple test website?

Tags: tls, ocsp

I'm interested in the status of OCSP respect in modern browsers (particularly the one I'm using right now).

Is there any website that will allow me to test how my browser treats the [`status_request` `SecurityPolicy`](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-hallambaker-muststaple-00.pdf#__WKANCHOR_m)?

I know that you can use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to test your *server* for just about everything, and [BadSSL](https://badssl.com/) to check your *browser*'s treatment of a variety of misconfigurations (HPKP revocation, SCT timestamp absence, etc.), but the latter does't seem to offer OCSP Must-Staple-without-Staple yet. Is there any website that *does*?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like let's encrypt [does support](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/improving-revocation-will-lets-encrypt-support-ocsp-must-staple/4334/39) the extension \([as does certbot](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/4be7efbf745c34ab13ee38c6f2fd5f08345de531/acme/acme/crypto_util.py#L171)\), so it should be pretty trivial to set up the site yourself.